# No consecutive spaces Swift UITextField

Tags: ios, regex, swift

How do I disable the user from typing two consecutive spaces in a UITextField?

The code I tried using is as follows:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let myString = myUITextField.text

    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: " +", options: .caseInsensitive)
    let trimmedString: String? = regex?.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString!, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (myString?.characters.count)!), withTemplate: " ")

    myUITextField.text = trimmedString

    let maxLegnth = 40
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let newString: NSString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    return newString.length <= maxLegnth
}
```

PS: The rest of the code forces the user to type in 40 characters only. This is another requirement.

Comment: Logically it is not a correct way to force the user not to type two consecutive spaces. if the requirement says it is up to 40 characters, it is fine. Other than that you can't make them type the contents as you like.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you can forcefully avoid wrong data typed into the textfield as per requirement for validation purpose or preventing attacks.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. it depends on the requirement. @Tarek has to confirm us about the requirement. If the requirement says it is not necessary it saves his work time.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Yes the requirement is to not have 2 consecutive spaces. 1 space is fine. 1 space + 1 any other character + 1 space + 1 any other character is also fine.

Comment: @Tarek, i believe that my solution have resolved your issue, so please accept it as correct answer so that it may help someone else in future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I was too busy in other parts of the project. I tried your solution and it worked perfectly. Time for me to integrate it with the part that limits the user's input to x number of characters.

Comment: I added my full code that satisfy both requirements as reply at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the previous and the current character entered by the user.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

if textField.text?.characters.last == " "  && string == " "{

// If consecutive spaces entered by user               
 return false
}

// If no consecutive space entered by user

return true

}
```

Comment: When is this function called

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria every time the user input something in `UItextfield`. For more details check  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the current displayed text in the textfield, with the new text that is being added. Then you can check for the occurence of `"  "`. If this string is detected return `false`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3,Xcode 8.2**

Prevent user from typing spacebar keys

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    //Restrict
    if string == " " && textField.text?.characters.last == " "{
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work. After first space the user will not be able to enter any character. check my answer.

Comment: @Maddy I'm not talking about your answer I'm talking about this answer

Comment: @Dhruv string argument never able to get 2 space at the same time so it will always return true

Comment: @ Nirav D,@Maddy: Please have a look into the updated solution, its now working

Answer (score 1):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let maxLegnth = 40
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let newString: NSString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    if textField.text?.characters.last == " " && string == " " {
        return false
    } else {
        return newString.length <= maxLegnth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //User never input space in text field(swift 5)...

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
     if string == " "   {
       // If consecutive spaces entered by user
       return false
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

how about replace "  "(two spaces) with " "(one spaces) all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression

```
var pattern=/(\s+){2,}/

 if(pattern.test(stringToCheck))
     {
    // string contain more than one consecutive space 
     }
```